# ExecuteNonQuery with DeleteCommand?

Tags: c#, mysql, executenonquery

I need use ExecuteNonQuery at those syntax's below?
And they are correct? Objective use the da.DeleteCommand; which syntax's I gain performance?

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM users_login WHERE UserID = @UserID;", coon);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = oUsuario.UserID;

MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
da.DeleteCommand = cmd;

coon.Open();
ok = true;

/**OR use this**/

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM users_login WHERE UserID = @UserID;", coon);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = oUsuario.UserID;

coon.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
ok = true;
```

Comment: You are asking if these commands are correct. Have you tried them? Are they working?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery should do it for delete also. Not sure about what delete command does.

Comment: If you want to execute the query immediately use `ExecuteNonQuery`, if you want to modify all in-memory in a `DataTable/DataSet` before you send the changes to the database use the `DataAdapter`.

Comment: I must have expressed myself badly I need this... If I use in a WebSite (Web Application), which sintaxes I gain performance?

Comment: @BrunoCasali: your question can not be answered. A DataAdapter can more than a Command alone. So if you need a DataAdapter use that, if you don't need it use the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you're executing a DELETE statement, ExecuteNonQuery() on your MySqlCommand instance is what you want to use.  It's also what you'd use if you're executing an INSERT or UPDATE statement or a stored procedure that doesn't return a resultset.

Comment: executing `da.DeleteCommand = cmd;` ? I gain Performance OR has the same resultset?

Comment: DataAdapters are for working with a DataSet.  If you're using a DataAdapter to fill, manipulate and post changes to a DataSet back to a database then it makes sense to use the DeleteCommand property on a DataAdapter instance.  If you just want to execute an arbitrary DELETE statement against a database then just use ExecuteNonQuery on a Command instance.

Comment: Thanks, you resolved part of the problem, but i need now:And About performance?

Comment: What about performance?  What specific concern about performance do you have?

Comment: Good, I discovered, two syntaxes to the same problem, i want know what are the syntaxes that I gain more performance?

Comment: On the surface it may seem like these are two solutions to the same problem but really they're not.  DataAdapter is specifically for working with a DataSet and propogating changes to that DataSet back to a database.  Command is for executing arbitrary SQL statements or stored procedures.  It doesn't make sense to discuss the performance of one approach vs. the other because they handle two different scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using a nonquery but the delete won't work... you may need to use a transaction:

```
coon.Open();
var trans = coon.BeginTransaction();

var query = "DELETE FROM users_login WHERE UserID = @UserID;";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, coon, trans);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = oUsuario.UserID;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

trans.Commit();
coon.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks dude, this worked for me as the usual last thing I tried after lots of other solutions.